# On Android, how to capture incoming packet on network layer (IP)?

Tags: android, networking, ip, vpn, packet

Currently, on the Android platform, there are Android apps that can capture the packets on the Application layer with the help of `VPNService`. However, as the document describes

> (using the fd returned by VPNService) each read from the descriptor retrieves an outgoing packet that was routed to the interface. Each write to the descriptor injects an incoming packet just like it was received from the interface.

It suggests we cannot get the incoming packets on the network layer (IP) by VPN; if we use a socket, we lose the granularity of network layer packets.

Is there any way to get the incoming IP packets on an Android device without rooting it?

Answer (score 0):

grab the packets on a network device instead like on your access point / switch / router / firewall. Usually they have build-in tools for that.
if you setup an accesspoint on your pc and connect phone to that it you can grab those packets  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CojA2ZZPiKs

Comment: there are lot of ways to do it on the router, PC，or rooted Android device, but they not what I am looking for.